# Microsoft access slider 6.0 create the max and min based on a query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, activex

Is it possible to set the max and min of a slider using a query in an access database? something like :

```
Dim x as double  

x = select count(mydata) from mytable;  

set me.Slider0.max = x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim x as double
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim s as string

s = "SELECT COUNT(mydata) FROM mytable"
rs = ThisDB.Execute(s)
x = Cint(rs)
Set Me!Slider0.Max = x
Set Me!Silder0.Min = x - x
```

Or something like that. Change for your min values.

Comment: Just figured it out right before you typed this hah! yep, I added it to the form load event and set the slider.max and min's. Thanks for the tip! In the future, how can i find out that the slider object has a max and min value in vba like that? I was searching everywhere and couldnt figure it out. Also, if you being typing slider0.ma- it usually pops up code complete, but not in this case.

Comment: I just added it to a form and looked through the controls. The MSDN documentation for it lacked any specific information, so playing in the debug window helped me.